# Android BLE Advertisements are not always sent to onScanResult()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are making an app that uses BLE advertisements to create first a list of our industrial devices. Then of course something else happens but this is not relevant for the question. What is important is that we need to receive BLE advertisements continuously.

There is a service-like object that starts scan ble, waits about 2 seconds then stops it.
After 500 milliseconds it starts again.
This continues endless.

Here below the code snippet to start the scan, for completeness, just standard code, as one can see:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null, new ScanSettings.Builder().
        setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .setReportDelay(0)
        .build(), bleScannerCallback);
    ok = true;
} else {
    ok = mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(bleScannerCallbackPreLollipop);
}

return ok;
```

the bleScannerCallback implements the callback to receive the `onScanResult()`.

What I'm experiencing right now is:

with some device, for example Samsung S6 with Android 5.1.1, within each scan cycle all devices in the proximity are received, i.e. `onScanResult()` runs with all BLE advertisements.

With some other device, like Tablet Nexus 9 with Android 7.0, everything runs fine for about 20 seconds, then for about 17/18 seconds NO advertisement is delivered through `onScanResult()`, then again ok for about 20 seconds, then again a break for about 17/18 seconds.

This process repeats infinitely, even with some regularity, it does not even seem random...

Is this a known issue?
It seems to appear specially with Android >= 6, our Samsung S6 with Android 5.1.1 runs all the times perfectly.

Obviously all the required Android permissions are in place, elsewhere it would not even run once.

It seems to me more a "feature" on the Android device to save some battery, unfortunately we need to scan continuously, at least in some condition, not really 24/7 but even not with about 20 seconds break every 20 seconds.

In the case this is the way it shall go in the future, does anyone know any other solution that allows to scan BLE devices continuously? Independently on the Android version...anyway the newer versions like >= 6.

Comment: Why do you stop/start the scanning all the time rather than letting it running all the time? You can set something else than SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY to let the hardware do that for you.

Comment: Hi Emil, first of all thanks for commenting. I jumped into this app on June this year, the communication part was already there, I'm still learning all the details about it. There is a quite a big mechanism behind, it is not so simple to make the suggested change. But just to make a test by increasing the timeout to a bigger value should be straightforward, then I can see whether I can receive all (or almost all) the packets. Anyway I read in these days that it is not recommended to start scan only once because in principle the App might receive packets only once after start scan.

Comment: My original comment was too long...I wanted to add that maybe what I wrote at the end was one of the reasons why the scan BLE was designed in this way.

Comment: Another reason might be that we let scan for devices only when the activity showing the device list is in foreground, therefore visible. There is no need to keep scanning when the App is doing something else. Once the user connects a device then everything runs fine, the GATT services seem to have no problem at all.

Comment: FYI recently android made a change such that if an app starts scanning more than 5 times in 30 seconds, the scanning attempt is blocked.

Comment: This looks a great hint...where can I find more details about this feature? If this is the future then it is clear that we have to change our scan mechanism...

Comment: It also matches my observations: the scan does not respond on a "almost" regular basis.